# 3D geographic plot with RGL

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, reshape, rgl

I am very new to reshape and rgl, to see if I had understood correctly I am going through the code presented in http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-3d-geographical-plots-in-r-using-rgl/ , it seems to work with the dataset presented in the website, but not with mine and i do not understand why, but what i get is only a grey image.
This is a link to my dataset http://www.mediafire.com/download/8ifpssvdyr665g7/sig.RData
as in the example the two columns are lat and long, the third is a value.
Is this the best way to plot data which are not on a grid?

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
library(rgl)
library(reshape)
rgl.clear(type = c("shapes"))
load("sig.RData")
calls = sig
calls=as.matrix(calls)
dimnames(calls) <- list(NULL, c("lat","long","total"))
calls<-as.data.frame(calls)

head(calls)
bin_size = 0.5
calls$long_bin = cut(calls$long, seq(min(calls$long), max(calls$long), bin_size))
calls$lat_bin = cut(calls$lat, seq(min(calls$lat), max(calls$lat), bin_size))
calls$total = log(calls$total) / 3 #need to do this to flatten out totals

calls = melt(calls[,3:5])

calls = cast(calls, lat_bin~long_bin, fun = sum, fill = 0)
calls = calls[,2:(ncol(calls)-1)]
calls = as.matrix(calls)

# simple black and white plot
x = (1: nrow(calls))
z = (1: ncol(calls))
rgl.surface(x, z, calls)
rgl.bringtotop()


rgl.pop()
# nicer colored plot
ylim <- range(calls)
ylen <- ylim[2] - ylim[1] + 1
col <- topo.colors(ylen)[ calls-ylim[1]+1 ]


x = (1: nrow(calls))
z = (1: ncol(calls))

rgl.bg(sphere=FALSE, color=c("black"), lit=FALSE)
rgl.viewpoint( theta = 300, phi = 30, fov = 170, zoom = 0.03)
rgl.surface(x, z, calls, color = col, shininess = 10)
rgl.bringtotop()
```